# AEM Author Slow

Tags: aem, aem-6

We are facing a situation where one of our AEM Author instances is very slow on a daily basis and we have already purged the old workflows on that author. Still we are facing a slow Author instance and we are not able to speed it up. Can anyone please help us; how to resolve this slow Author issue?

Comment: How to resolve permanantly this Author slowness issue ?

Comment: Refer to page : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-cloud-kcs/kbarticles/KA-17457.html?lang=en

Comment: There can be many reasons: running low on storage, RAM, concurrent authors, assets processing, replication queues blocked, etc. More details and logs are needed.